How to explain the this pointer in JavaScript?
I try to print this in two ways. But get different results. How to explain this.
function A(executor){
    this.data = 1;
    this.executor = executor;
    this.executor();

}


function printThis(){
    console.log(this);
    
}



let a = new A(()=>{
    console.log(this);
})

let b = new A(printThis);

In a, this = {}
In b, this = A{data:1, executor:[Function:printThis]}
The executor function are used in A. But why, the results are different?

simply explained by understanding arrow functions

TL;DR: arrow functions bind their own this context, it is not dependent on how the function is called. That's one of their primary features.

What environment are you running under?  In a browser, "a" outputs Window.

I’m running this code in NodeJs env.

Maybe I have understood it. But still a little confused. It seems that the 'this' pointer is defined as long as we defined an arrow function. So in this case, no matter where we use the function ()=>{log(this)}, 'this' is always the value when it was defined, which is global this.

Have you checked the related answers linked above? In general, also read up on JavaScript documentation, like MDN - JavaScript - this.
